# How to create a new quantum gate and qubit initialised to a certain value

Tags: python-3.x, linear-algebra, quantum-computing, qiskit

I am trying to implement the Quantum HHL algorithm on QISKit package of IBM on Python. I have tried searching the documentation for a method to initialize a  qubit to a certain value and to create a new unitary gate with specified values.

In the documentation, I found [this](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-sdk-py/blob/master/qiskit/_gate.py), which is the class of a Quantum Gate. I tried to make a new instance of this class but I couldn't because not much documentation has been done about the arguments to be passed while initializing the instance of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of QISKit v0.4.9, the [`u3()`](https://www.qiskit.org/documentation/_autodoc/qiskit.extensions.standard.html#qiskit.extensions.standard.u3) function parametrizes an arbitrary single-qubit unitary gate *U(θ, φ, λ)* (for details, [see](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.03429.pdf) formula (2)). Obviously, you can use the `u3()` function to set a qubit to any value.

For example, this is how you can implement the *X*-gate and apply it to some qubit `qr[0]` via the *U3*-gate:

```python
u3(theta=math.pi, phi=0, lam=0, q=qr[0])
```

Comment: Is there a way to create generic n Qubit gates ?

Comment: @ParthJatakia, if you want to run on the real hardware, you would need to manually decompose your particular unitary matrix into a sequence of the *CNOT*- and *U3*-gates. Then, you might want to keep it as your own extension (see [github](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-sdk-py/tree/master/qiskit/extensions/standard) for how it is done for the standard gates).